# Meteor - Website doesn't work in the production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

The project I am working on, works in the development environment. But when I deploy it live and navigate to the site, I only see blank screen.

I get the following errors in the console (from both development and production environment)
[image: Console Errors]

The same error exists in the development and production environments. The different is, I can navigate through the site pages in the development environment. But I only see a blank screen in the production environment.

I tried to update my jQuery to the latest version using the following command:

```
meteor npm install --save jquery meteor-node-stubs
```

But I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue cost me some time to work out. Basically you need to find a sweet spot for jquery.

Meteor loads jquery by default, and in .meteor/packages I have jquery@1.11.10, which is probably what Meteor puts in for you.

You will also need to load a version somewhere in between that works. For me this command did the trick:

```
meteor npm install jquery@2.2.4
```

Cheers

Comment: I have jquery version 1.11.10 in .meteor/packages. I tried to use the above command. I end up with the following error "jquery@2.2.4  invalid".

Comment: I am on Ubuntu and I face the same error as Behrouz